# Selenium web driver JS : ECONNRESET socket hang up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When i am trying to do UI automation testing in AWS Code build getting this error

Error: ECONNRESET socket hang up
at ClientRequest. (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:294:15)

I am using standalone selenium docker for firefox inside AWS Code build with linux environment.

Same script is working in local machines

Comment: Are you trying to access an page on a local web server on your local network?

Answer (score 1):

Please verify selenium running on port 4444